# Florida Sitecore User Group - February 27, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Date/Time (EST):** Tuesday, February 27, 2018, 6:00 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** Tuesday, February 27, 2017, 11:00 PM

**Location:** ConnectWise, 4925 Independence Pkwy #400, Tampa, FL 33634

**RSVP:** https://www.meetup.com/Florida-Sitecore-User-Group/events/247157845/

**Agenda:**

6:00-6:30 PM (11 to 11:30 UTC): Drinks, Snacks and Networking

6:30-7:00 PM (11:30 to 12 UTC): James Williamson & Chris Auer will present how to use Data Exchange Framework to solve multi-system integration challenges.

7:00-7:30 PM (12 to 12:30 UTC): Greg Rice will present Sitecore Search Solution, a SOLR-based add-on search module for existing Sitecore installations, built by Alpha Solutions.

7:30-8:00 PM (12:30 to 1 UTC): Open discussion / forum among all attendees. Ask questions, talk about hot topics, etc.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began Feb 17 at 11:00